# How to put the SUM field in a crystal report to Section3(Details)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Is their any way to locate the sum field in a crystal report in the `Details Section?` **"Section3(Details)"**. Because I'm working on a receipt and I don't want to generate a list. I just following the same exact format of the receipt which has a `total amount`. Or I just put it in the **Report Footer?** Here is my receipt just in case you have other approach or any other way to work with the same exact format.

[image]

Comment: if the Particulars and Amounts are details then you should required subreport for these. You can create a sub report and place it on the left side. But, if your question is "Can I place Sum of field in Detail section then it is possible by creating formula field and place Sum({FieldName}, [{groupByfieldName}]). groupbyfieldname is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to generate the list.. put the sum in **Report Footer** and supress the detail section in crystal report.